# Process a collection at a timed interval or when it reaches a certain size

Tags: clojure

I am reading Strings in from the standard input with

```
(line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))
```

How can I:

1. Store the lines in a collection
2. At some interval (say 5 minutes) process the collection and also
3. Process the collection as soon as its size grows to n (say 10) regardless of timing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i left you my purposes:

1. As you can check in http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/line-seq the result of`(line-seq (BufferedReader. xxx))` is a sequence, so this function stores the result (return  a new ) collection
2. You can do it with clojure/core.async timeout function http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/timeout, you can take a look at https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/examples/walkthrough.clj to get acquainted with the library
3. Just use a conditional (if, when ...) to check the count of the collection

Answer (score 1):

As @tangrammer says, core-async would be a good way to go, or [Lamina](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina) (sample-every)

Answer (score 0):

I pieced something together using a single atom. You probably have to adjust things to your need (e.g. parallel execution, not using a future to create the periodic processing thread, return values, ...). The following code creates `processor-with-interval-and-threshold`, a function creating another function that can be given a seq of elements which is processed in the way you described.

```
(defn- periodically!
  [interval f]
  (future
    (while true
      (Thread/sleep interval)
      (f))))

(defn- build-head-and-tail
  [{:keys [head tail]} n elements]
  (let [[a b] (->> (concat tail elements)
                   (split-at n))]
    {:head (concat head a) :tail b}))

(defn- build-ready-elements
  [{:keys [head tail]}]
  {:ready (concat head tail)})

(defn processor-with-interval-and-threshold
  [interval threshold f]
  (let [q (atom {})]
    (letfn [(process-elements! []
              (let [{:keys [ready]} (swap! q build-ready-elements)]
                (when-not (empty? ready)
                  (f ready))))]
      (periodically! interval process-elements!)
      (fn [sq]
        (let [{:keys [head]} (swap! q build-head-and-tail threshold sq)]
          (when (>= (count head) threshold)
            (process-elements!)))))))
```

The atom `q` manages a map of three elements:

- `:head`: a seq that gets filled first and checked against the threshold,
- `:tail`: a seq with the elements that exceed the threshold (possibly lazy),
- `:ready`: elements to be processed.

Now, you could for example do the following:

```
(let [add! (processor-with-interval-and-threshold 300000 10 your-fn)]
  (doseq [x (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))]
    (add! [x])))
```

That should be enough to get you started, I guess.